# Does the QR Iteration work for non symmetric matrices as well?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

We know that the QR iteration is a method to obtain the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of a full rank, symmetric matrix. I was wondering if this can be extended to non-symmetric matrices as well.

Comment: The QR algorithm can work on a general n x n matrix but it might take longer.